# Error on fetching events from Google Calander(version='v3') in python web-application

Tags: events, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I'm using FLOW api to make authorization to access Google calendar through my application, in Google calendar version 'v3'.

Authentication is perfectly done but when trying to access that specific person's event from that person's Google Calendar at that time getting following error.

```
HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?alt=json&key='DEVELOPER_KEY' returned "Not Found">
```

while goggled lot on this but unable to solve the same error.

I'm using following code snippet for fetching out event from Google calendar.

```
events = service.events().list(calendarId='primary').execute() #fetch out events for first time
while True:
    for event in events.get('items', []):
        print event['summary']
    page_token = events.get('nextPageToken') #check if any event present in next page of the calendar
    if page_token:
        events = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', pageToken=page_token).execute()
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the string 'primary' with the user's full email address:

```
events = service.events().list(calendarId='myuser@gmail.com').execute() #fetch out events for first time
while True:
    for event in events.get('items', []):
        print event['summary']
    page_token = events.get('nextPageToken') #check if any event present in next page of the calendar
    if page_token:
        events = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', pageToken=page_token).execute()
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Thanks Jay for the answer, but not able to solve my problem still. (i.e. same error still)

Comment: Can you show more details (code) about how you are authenticating?